# Divergence and convergence tests: $\sum\left(\frac n{n+22}\right)^n$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

[image]

Hi! I am currently working on some calc2 online homework problems and I am having a hard time with this one question. I did try the root test but that was inconclusive because the limit $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac n{n+22}=1$. If someone could help me solve this problem using any convergence or divergent method, I would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \left(\frac{n}{n+22}\right)^n = e^{-22} $$

This series diverges by the limit test or the $n$th term test.

The problem says to use "any method" covered so far even though it is in the "ratio and root test" section.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: @Brad Could you justify the equality that you've given, rather than simply stating it?

Comment: It's a fair assumption that a calc 2 student might know $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{n}{n+22}\right)^n =\left.1\middle/\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac{22}{n}\right)^n\right. =\left.1\middle/e^{22}\right.$$

Answer (score 2):

We have

$$u_n=\left(\frac n{22+n}\right)^n=\exp\left(-n\log\left(1+\frac{22}{n}\right)\right)\sim_\infty e^{-22}$$
hence the given series is divergent since the sequence doesn't converge to $0$.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: You're welcome.

Answer (score 1):

$a_n$ does no goes to $0$.

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} (\frac{n}{n + 22}) ^n = e^{-22}$$ so the series cannot converge

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!